# No friends or Family in the schengen territory, Do i need Invitation?

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, nigerian-citizens

If I do not have a family member in the schengen territory, Now What i want to know is, should I not have a family member there that can send me an Invitation, Can I still apply? I just have plan on going there for some Tour and come back, I have booked a tourist Itinerary and hotel reservation confirmation and included my bank statements , ID Card and Payslip and other documents.

Please I do need clarity on this one. I am Nigerian.

Comment: Where you book your "tourist Itinerary"? A local travel agent? They should help you. In any case, not having "friends and family in Schengen" is a big plus.

Answer (score 2):

On the application form, select **Tourism** (field 21) as the main purpose of your journey.

Other that your passport is lacking, your collection of documents should be complete.

Comment: So i just add my itinerary , hotel reservation, passport, bank statements , and other documents (eg. payslips etc) Correct?

Comment: @Oyenusi Yes that should be fine,.